# How do I use service methods inside an @Secured expression?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I'm using `Grails` with `spring-security-core:2.0-RC4`

I am trying to do some custom security checks inside my @Secured expression, like so:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;

class AdminController {
    def myCustomSecService;

    @Secured("@myCustomSecService.customCheck()")
    def index() {
        render(view:"index")
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work at all.
I have seen similar [examples](http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/10/grails-calling-bean-methods-in-spring.html) with `@PreAuthorize`, but that (apparently) requires the `spring-security-acl` plugin which I would like to avoid using (unless I really really have to).

Oddly enough, `spring-security-core` plugin includes a `jar` with both the `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: One option is to replace the default `AuthenticationProvider` bean with your own implementation. Have a look at this blog post and the accompanying sample app for details: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090

Comment: I'll have a look and post some results if it works! Thanks :)

Comment: I see how I can work with that example but it seems like it would hide the type of check. If I was able to access a service directly, just by looking at the `@Secured` annotation I'd know how that controller is being secured.

Comment: It's true that it won't be as obvious what custom checks are being performed if they are "hidden" inside your own `AuthenticationProvider` compared with the `@Secured` proposal. However, the `AuthenticationProvider` solution should work, whereas the `@Secured` solution doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean the `@Secured` doesn't work? The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#expressions) says it should be able to take a SpEL expression.

All it needs is something like a bean resolver to find out what the service I want to call is... right?

Comment: I meant that based on your experience, it doesn't work, even if the docs says it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I think I have found a solution.

I saw somewhere that if I had to override classes and methods while using Spring I was probably doing something wrong.

All I needed to do was add @Component to my service

Here's what I came I ended up doing:

My controller:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;

class AdminController {
    def myCustomSecService;

    @Secured("@myCustomSecService.customCheck()")
    def index() {
        render(view:"index")
    }
}
```

and my service:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("myCustomSecService")
class MyCustomSecService {
    def customCheck() {
        /*do checks here*/
        return true;
    }
}
```